# How a passing dynamic parameter could work along with passing props in React-Router

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-router

I'm performing an Ajax request and I present the data inside a component in the form of a table. I'm using `<Link/>` inside the table, that passes the dynamic parameter `id` from the pathname `/competitions/${comp.id}` to the Route path of the React-Router `<Route path='/competitions/:id' component={Teams}></Route>`. The parameter `id` is used to perform an Ajax request inside the `Teams` component which provides a url in the form of `http://localhost:3000/competitions/426`.

For clarification reasons, I'd prefer for the url to show the parameter of the selected `league` which corresponds to a particular `id` (i.e. `http://localhost:3000/competitions/EC`). So I tried to do that onClick and pass the `id` as props to the `Teams` component for the Ajax request, but the Router doesn't work correctly. What I came up with was the solution of the `query` property inside `<Link/>` as `<Link to={{pathname:'/competitions/${comp.id}',query:{league:comp.league}}}>` that gives a url like `http://localhost:3000/competitions/426?league=PL` which in a way solves my problem.

My question is if there is another way to pass both the clicked `league` and `id` to the `Teams` component in order to match the url with the correct data?

This is the component `CompetitionsTable` that grabs the data:

```
class CompetitionsTable extends Component {

 render() {
  let list = this.props.data.map(function (comp, i) {
   return (
    <tr key={i+1}>
      <th scope="row">{i+1}</th>
      <td className={comp.id}> <Link to={{pathname:`/competitions/${comp.id}`,query:{league:comp.league}}}> {comp.caption} </Link></td>
      <td>{comp.league}</td>
      <td>{comp.numberOfTeams}</td>
    </tr>
   );
  }, this);

 return (
  <tbody>{list}</tbody>
 );
}};
```

The `App` component with the `Router`:

```
class App extends Component {

 render() {
 return (
  <Router key={Math.random()} history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Output}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path='/competitions' component={Competitions}></Route>
      <Route path='/competitions/:id' component={Teams}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
 )}}
```

And this is the `Teams` component:

```
class Teams extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   teamData: [],
   source: "",
  }}

 componentWillMount(){this.dataSource();}

 dataSource(props) {
  var url = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/x/teams';
  this.setState({source: url.replace(url.split('/')[5],  this.props.params.id)});
 }

 getTeamsData(){
  $.ajax({
   headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': '************************' },
   url:this.state.source,
   dataType:'json',
   cache:false,
   success: function(data){
    this.setState({teamData: data.teams});
   }.bind(this),
   error: function(xhr, status, err){
    console.log(err);
   }
  })}

 componentDidMount(){this.getTeamsData();}
```

Comment: Can you add an extra paramater to route like `path='/competitions/:id/:league'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass both the id and the league name like
`<Route path='/competitions/:league/:id/' component={Teams}></Route>` 
and then use only the id parameter for your ajax call.
That gives a url like
    `http://localhost:3000/competitions/PL/426`

Comment: yes that would work, but I don't know if it's right, because it implies the existence of an intermediate path `http://localhost:3000/competitions/PL` that doesn't really exist.

Comment: You can make a parameter optional by wrapping inside braces. `<Route path='/competitions/:league(/:id)`

Comment: @Hardik Modha I tried that and the thing is when you click on the `<Link/>`, the path, although id is optional, has a default form of `http://localhost:3000/competitions/PL/426`. When I alternatively try to load this one `http://localhost:3000/competitions/PL` which should also work, the ajax request can't load, because it needs `this.props.params.id` passed from the Route path.

Comment: Then you can just reverse the order of parameters. `<Route path='/competitions/:id(/:league)`

Comment: @Hardik Modha sure I could. But my question is whether there is a more clear solution to the problem of how a passing parameter could work along with passing props from Router to a particular component.